# Dependency errors after failed ugrade Ubuntu 14.04 > 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, dpkg, dependencies

I tried upgrading my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 but after reboot several applications aren't working anymore. The problem is several dependancy errors.

Output `sudo dpkg -a --configure`:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ure:
 ure depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package ure (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of duplicity:
 duplicity depends on python-lockfile (>> 1:0.9); however:
  Version of python-lockfile on system is 1:0.8-2ubuntu2.

dpkg: error processing package duplicity (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Version of python3 on system is 3.4.0-0ubuntu2.
 python3-uno depends on python3.5; however:
  Package python3.5 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libpython3.5 (>= 3.5.0~b1); however:
  Package libpython3.5 is not installed.
 python3-uno depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.
 python3-uno depends on ure; however:
  Package ure is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpoppler58:amd64:
 libpoppler58:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.9); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package libpoppler58:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev:amd64:
 libc6-dev:amd64 depends on libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.9.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64:
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 depends on libgnome-desktop-3-12 (= 3.18.1-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgnome-desktop-3-12 is not installed.
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 depends on gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 (= 3.18.1-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 is not installed.
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.3.6); however:
  Package libgtk-3-dev is not installed.
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 depends on gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev; however:
  Package gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev is not installed.
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 depends on libxkbfile-dev; however:
  Package libxkbfile-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc-dev-bin:
 libc-dev-bin depends on libc6 (>> 2.23); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.19-0ubuntu6.9.

dpkg: error processing package libc-dev-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-pptp:
 network-manager-pptp depends on libnm0 (>= 1.1.90); however:
  Package libnm0 is not installed.
 network-manager-pptp depends on ppp (>= 2.4.7-1+~); however:
  Version of ppp on system is 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-pptp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ppp:
 network-manager (1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) breaks ppp (<< 2.4.6) and is unpacked but not configured.
  Version of ppp to be configured is 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2.

dpkg: error processing package ppp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of uno-libs3:
 uno-libs3 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package uno-libs3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libicu55:amd64:
 libicu55:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 5.2); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3.

dpkg: error processing package libicu55:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-bin:
 libglib2.0-bin depends on libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.40.2-0ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of deja-dup:
 deja-dup depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2); however:
  Version of libgtk-3-0:amd64 on system is 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6.
 deja-dup depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package deja-dup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager:
 network-manager depends on libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.0); however:
  Package libgnutls30 is not installed.
 network-manager depends on libndp0 (>= 1.2); however:
  Package libndp0 is not installed.
 network-manager depends on libnm0 (>= 1.1.93); however:
  Package libnm0 is not installed.
 network-manager depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~); however:
  Version of init-system-helpers on system is 1.14.
 network-manager depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7); however:
  Version of lsb-base on system is 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6.
 network-manager depends on isc-dhcp-client (>= 4.3.1-5ubuntu1); however:
  Version of isc-dhcp-client on system is 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.4.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g-dev:amd64:
 zlib1g-dev:amd64 depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev; however:
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libc-dev is not installed.
  Package libc6-dev:amd64 which provides libc-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zlib1g-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-pptp-gnome:
 network-manager-pptp-gnome depends on libnm-gtk0 (>= 1.0.6); however:
  Version of libnm-gtk0 on system is 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.4.
 network-manager-pptp-gnome depends on libnm0 (>= 1.1.90); however:
  Package libnm0 is not installed.
 network-manager-pptp-gnome depends on libnma0 (>= 1.1.90); however:
  Package libnma0 is not installed.
 network-manager-pptp-gnome depends on network-manager-pptp (= 1.1.93-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package network-manager-pptp is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-pptp-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedit2:amd64:
 libedit2:amd64 depends on libtinfo5 (>= 6); however:
  Version of libtinfo5:amd64 on system is 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libedit2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedit2:i386:
 libedit2:i386 depends on libtinfo5 (>= 6); however:
  Version of libtinfo5:i386 on system is 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libedit2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-gnome:
 network-manager-gnome depends on libnm0 (>= 1.1.90); however:
  Package libnm0 is not installed.
 network-manager-gnome depends on libnma0 (= 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package libnma0 is not installed.
 network-manager-gnome depends on network-manager (>= 1.1); however:
  Package network-manager is not configured yet.
 network-manager-gnome depends on adwaita-icon-theme; however:
  Package adwaita-icon-theme is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-sendto:
 nautilus-sendto depends on nautilus (>= 1:2.91); however:
  Package nautilus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-sendto (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ure
 duplicity
 python3-uno
 libpoppler58:amd64
 libc6-dev:amd64
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev:amd64
 libc-dev-bin
 network-manager-pptp
 ppp
 uno-libs3
 libicu55:amd64
 libglib2.0-bin
 deja-dup
 network-manager
 zlib1g-dev:amd64
 network-manager-pptp-gnome
 libedit2:amd64
 libedit2:i386
 network-manager-gnome
 nautilus-sendto
```

I already tried lots of things, like:

- changing sources.list
- running following commands:

  sudo apt-get clean

  ```
  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install -f

  sudo dpkg -a --configure

  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Output sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 deja-dup : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 is installed
            Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not installable
 duplicity : Depends: python-lockfile (> 1:0.9) but 1:0.8-2ubuntu2 is installed
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.23) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is installed
 libedit2 : Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libedit2:i386 : Depends: libtinfo5:i386 (>= 6) but 5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgnome-desktop-3-dev : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-12 (= 3.18.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not installable
                          Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 (= 3.18.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libgtk-3-dev (>= 3.3.6) but it is not installed
                          Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev but it is not installed
                          Depends: libxkbfile-dev but it is not installed
 libicu55 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
 libpoppler58 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
 nautilus : Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-12 (>= 3.18.1) but it is not installable
            Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2) but 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6 is installed
            Depends: libtracker-sparql-1.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: nautilus-data (>= 1:3.18) but 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.11 is installed
 network-manager : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libndp0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installed
                   Depends: libnm0 (>= 1.1.93) but it is not installable
                   Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is installed
                   Depends: lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu7) but 4.1+Debian11ubuntu6 is installed
                   Depends: isc-dhcp-client (>= 4.3.1-5ubuntu1) but 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.4 is installed
                   Recommends: ppp (>= 2.4.6) but 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2 is installed
                   Recommends: modemmanager
                   Breaks: ppp (< 2.4.6) but 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2 is installed
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libnm0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libnma0 (= 1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but it is not installable
                         Depends: adwaita-icon-theme but it is not installable
 network-manager-pptp : Depends: libnm0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not installable
                        Depends: ppp (>= 2.4.7-1+~) but 2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2 is installed
 network-manager-pptp-gnome : Depends: libnm-gtk0 (>= 1.0.6) but 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
                              Depends: libnm0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not installable
                              Depends: libnma0 (>= 1.1.90) but it is not installable
 python3-uno : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
               Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
               Depends: python3.5 but it is not installable
               Depends: libpython3.5 (>= 3.5.0~b1) but it is not installable
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
 uno-libs3 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
 ure : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Anyone have an idea how I can fix these dependencies? 
The biggest problem is that I can not open nautilus and network manager. So wireless is no option, got my ethernet working by adding eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces